# Multiple toAddresses in sendEmail

Tags: email, soap-api

Trying to use sendEmail() SOAP functionality (generating XML as in [this example](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Partner_Send_Email)).

According to the [sendEmail() documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm) you can use a list of emails in the toAddresses field.

How are these delimited in the SOAP XML message? I have tried space and comma but neither seems to work.

Comment: So you tried message.setToAddresses(new String[] { "person3@salesforce.com", "person4@salesforce.com" });

Comment: try semi-colon?

Comment: semi-colon does not seem to work either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not delimited within the `<toAddresses>` element instead you should have multiple `<toAddresses>` elements, one for each address.

Answer (score 1):

It's not delimited, you provide an array of strings, where each item in the array is an email address you want to send to.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'test@test.com'};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
```

Comment: I am constructing the XML myself. How are they delimited in the XML?

Comment: Aha, but you didn't say anything about SOAP before, i'm sorry, I don't have experience with the SOAP API nor constructing it via XML

Comment: @PJC Always i prefer watching the Tag:).

Comment: Just wondering if there's a reason you're not just using the wrapper classes in Java / C# which would generate the XML for you ?

Comment: I did mention SOAP but didn't make it clear that I needed to construct the XML myself. Sorry. I am working on a desktop C app so cannot use the Java / C# examples.

Comment: Might be the quickest to load the WSDL into SOAP UI and test it out.  Would save you the trouble of fine tuning the structure in C

Comment: What is the REST parallel for sending a mail through the API?